# When a post increases its asked scope, should a new question be posted?

Tags: discussion, questions

In this post, *[How do I trigger a JavaScript function from a select element when the select element no longer exists in a normal manner?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51130330)*, the scope of the original question increased with an additional question (in a comment), where I decided it where within reason and updated my answer with yet a solution.

Then one more question came, for which I then decided it weren't within reason/range given the original question.

After explaining to the OP (through a series of comments), that one is supposed to post a new, they simple came back with saying to *"not make them jump through hoops on technicalities about policy"*.

Am I wrong here, in this case, and should be keep on answering?

<strike>As a note, [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51130330/how-to-trigger-a-js-function-from-a-select-element-when-the-select-element-no-lo#comment89347887_51130462) holds the question I found being not within reasonable scope.</strike>
<sup>As all the comments at the mentioned post's answer have been deleted, the link in the above note is no longer valid</sup>